# Fill a div to 100% width within x secounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fill my div to 100% width. In normalstate it's 0%. This should happen in x secounds, because I want to make a little timebar which shows how long this image will stay until the next comes.

An example would be this slider:

https://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-slideshow-with-ribbon-decoration/

I want to do this little bar on the bottom.

I tried an interval which adds every 1ms "((FULLWIDTH/100)/8000)%" to the div, but it won't work (8000 for 8 secounds)

How could I realize this?

Greetings,

Janik

Comment: add the code, that you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
@keyframes example {
from {width: 0;}
to {width: 100%;}
}
.bar{
height: 5px;
background: #000;
width: 0;
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgnojc56/

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a JS fallback using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
              {
                  $('.bar').animate({width: '100%'}, 5000);
              });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p5nmnbty/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following css to div element:

```
div {
   background:grey;
   width:0%;
   -webkit-transition: width 8s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: width 8s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: width 8s ease-in-out;
   transition: width 8s ease-in-out;
}
```

and then add width `100%`:

```
$('div').css('width','100%')
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gpb4tk6v/)**

Comment: Wow thanks that's also really nice!

But when should I set it to 100% by js?

Comment: do you want this on load??

Comment: on load, on pic change etc. but afelixj did it without js it works very well i can run it via addClass :) but thanks for your reply